# Nvidia Optix :rtProgramCreateFromPTXFile or rtProgramCreateFromPTXString returns the RT_ERROR_INVALID_SOURCE?

Tags: optix

```
RTresult code = rtProgramCreateFromPTXString(context, pBuf, "draw_solid_color", &ray_gen_program);
```

The code result is

```
RT_ERROR_INVALID_SOURCE
```

My project can generate PTX file, and the cuda and optix are configured.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: 1) Make sure the string `pBuf` points to is well formed and null-terminated 2) Check the PTX bitness (should probably be 64 from now on) 3) No debug info in the PTX

Comment: thanks,i resolved.

Comment: Glad to know. I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since these steps solved your issue, I'm making this an answer:

1. Make sure the string pBuf points to is well formed and null-terminated
2. Check the PTX bitness (should probably be 64 from now on)
3. No debug info in the PTX